# Matlab: Create function with another function as argument

Tags: matlab

I need to create a function `f` with another function, `g`, as argument (`g` is defined in a `.m` file, not `inline`). In the body of `f`, I need to use `feval` to evaluate `g` on multiple values; something like:

```
function y = f(a,b,c,g)
 z=feval(g,a,b,c);
 y=...
end
```

What is the syntax ? I tried to use handles, but I got error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

1. Define `f` in an m-file:

   ```
   function y = f(a,b,c,g)
       y = feval(g,a,b,c);
   end
   ```
2. Define `g` in an m-file:

   ```
   function r = g(a,b,c)
       r = a+b*c;
   end
   ```
3. Call `f` with a handle to `g`:

   ```
   >> f(1,2,3,@g)
   ans =
        7
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change the body of `add`, then you could do that:

```
function s = add_two(a)
  s = a + 2;
end

function s = add_three(a)
  s = a + 3;
end

function s = add(a, fhandle1, fhandle2)
  s = feval(fhandle1, a);
  s = s + feval(fhandle2, s);
end

a = 10;
fhandle1 = @add_two;            // function handler
fhandle2 = @add_three;
a = add(a, fhandle1, fhandle2);
a
```

Comment: Ok, but then with your solution if I want to change the argument of add, I need to rewrite add.

Comment: @Gonzague, I included an example with `eval` and a `function handler`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, for example if I want to use add_four and add_five instead of add_two and add_three, then I need to change acordingly in the body of add.

Comment: @Gonzague sorry for not getting that by the first moment, edited!